# How to add an image stored in variable in a tab on click on a button in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to store a gif in a variable called gifCharles, in the data section of my component in Vuejs. Then everytime i click on a button the image is pushed to a tab that is stored in the variable gifTab, thank to the method NumberMatch.
Unfortunately I can't seem to make it work anyone can help me please?
here is the code:

```
<!-- SCRIPT-->
<script>

export default {
   name:'Body',
   data() {
       return {
           luckyNumber:'',
           randomNumber:'',
           number: 0,
           gifCharles:require("../assets/jpg/isolation-charles.png"),
           gifTab:[],
           scoresTab:[],
           total:0,
       }
   },

       methods: {
           RandomNumbGenerator(){
               this.randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
               return this.randomNumber
           },

           InputValue(){
               this.luckyNumber = document.getElementById("input_lucky_numb").value;
           },

           NumberMatch(){
               if(this.randomNumber == this.luckyNumber){
                 var tabGif = this.gifTab.push(this.gifCharles)
                 return tabGif
               }
           }
       },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push -- Is a *mutable* event. This means it doesn't return the new object and instead modifies the original object.

In `NumberMatch`, Try either:

Keeping push, and referencing `this.gifTab` instead of the output of `NumberMatch`.

Or switching to `concat`, and returning that result.

```
             this.gifTab = this.gifTab.concat(this.gifCharles)
             return this.gifTab
```

TLDR; push returns "The new length property of the object upon which the method was called." not the new value. `concat` has behavior you want instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the methods works but the image doesn't show instead the path of the image appears in the tab (on the page of the browser) like a string value: [ "/img/isolation-charles.cb0b74c9.png" ] . I want the image to show. Any idea? here is the div where it is supposed to appear in the template:  <div class="body_tab_gifs"  > {{this.gifTab}} </div>